# How to automatically delete container registry images related to an argocd application when application gets deleted?

Tags: cicd, azure-container-registry, argocd

I was wondering if there is any fancy way to delete images from the container registry when the application deleted?

When `argocd` deletes application, images made in CI process stick around and don't get deleted automatically which is not desirable, have you any idea how to solve this issue for both `application` and `application-set` definition in a clean way?

Comment: Maybe ArgoCD delete post hook?

Comment: Though, I would have an auto cleaning strategy in the registry anyway. It shouldn't be Argo responsibility to cleanup.

Comment: One way to automatically delete container registry images related to an argocd application when the application gets deleted is to use Azure Container Registry's acr purge command. This command can be run as an on-demand or scheduled ACR Task to delete all tags that are older than a certain duration or match a specified name filter.

Comment: References:

-   [Automatically purge images from an Azure container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge#automatically-purge-images-from-an-azure-container-registry)
-   [Best practices for Azure Container Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-best-practices#manage-registry-size)

Comment: @Arko Thanks, i was more looking for a way to handle it in argocd, something like application resources which automatically removed when application is deleted or subscribe to an event.